# How to remove Google Drive "Quick access"?

Tags: google-drive

On the page https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive, there's a "Quick Access" section, which takes up as annoying much as half the page.

Is there a **built-in** functionality to remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Quick Access setting. Now you can turn on default My Drive view by switching setting in Google Drive, `Settings > General > Start page`, turn it to **My Drive** to open default list of Drive files when you open Drive:

[image]

Comment: I wonder why it's on by default..